# use variable type to define another variable type

Tags: java

Im trying to use the type of one variable to define the type on another
I know i could just put all the types in an enum then use ordinal with a switch/case to select but i'm wondering if theres an easier way.

Heres a small example:

```
public void loadRotation(TetrominoType type) {
TetrominoType new = new type.class();
}

TetroiminoType type = new RedTetro();
this.loadRotation(type);
```

RedTetro obviously extends TetrminoType

I know this won't work but hopefully from it you understand what i'm trying to do.

Comment: Assuming an *object* is passed, see the [`Object.getClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method and follow the links from there -- which would allow reflection utilization. Other options include passing in a `Class<...>` or using a "factory pattern".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection is the answer.

If you're talking about a class that has a zero argument constructor, it's quite straight forward:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
MyClass c2 = c.getClass().newInstance();
```

If you need to use a constructor that takes arguments you have to extract the `Constructor` you need and use that. Oracle provides a tutorial here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

Answer (score 1):

you could use the `instanceof` evaluator:

```
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] a) {

    String s = "Hello";
    if (s instanceof java.lang.String) {
      System.out.println("is a String");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: But theres 7 different types, i was trying to avoid writing a condition statement for each class

Comment: This also doesn't really answer the fundamental question: how to pass a type-*constructor* to a method?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java reflection to rewrite the type based on the type of the variable you have.

You can find out more here http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/ and a similar problem here [Dynamic variables with given type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3440651/dynamic-variables-with-given-type)

It should be a case of utilising the base class of your type too set a basic type and then using reflection to create the variable with the new type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up the Factory design pattern.